# How to pass a character pointer to a function

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am trying to solve a problem in which I have to take a character pointer and store an email and then  pass that pointer to a function so that I can verify if there are any special characters in the input string.
Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void verify(char** em)
{
    char *z = *em;

    while(*z)
    {
        printf("%c", *z++);  
    }

    while(*z != '\n')
    {
        if(*z == 'a')
        {
            printf("present");
            *z++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("not present");
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    char *email = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

    printf("enter the email id\n");
    scanf("%100s", email);

    while(*email)
    {
        printf("%c", *email++);  
    }

    verify(&email);
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I pass the character pointer to my function verify() and try to print the string, I don't get the required output.

how can i use this function to verify if any input email is valid or not?
i am trying to find the index of '@' and check for characters before @ and after @,but i don't know how can i store the index of '@' because it is not an array.

Comment: You should properly format and indent your code before doing anything else.

Comment: Not related to the post's question, just want to point that you may have a memory leak. For each piece `malloc`ed, please make sure you free it.

Comment: Your `scanf()` should be `scanf("%99s",email)` since the field width doesn't include the terminating null.  Also, why are you printing null-terminated strings one character at a time?

Comment: Also, you probably want your loop to end when the special character is found, and to only print "not present" after the loop finishes without finding it... as is, you'll print one of your messages for every character in the string (after fixing the other issues with losing the start of the string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1**

The lines

```
while(*email)
    printf("%c",*email++);
```

move `email` so that it points to the end of the string at the end of the loop. You need to keep track of the original value of `email`.

```
char* it = email;
while(*it)
    printf("%c",*it++);
```

**Problem 2**

You are not deallocating the memory you got in the call to `malloc`.

**Problem 3**

The lines

```
 while(*z)
   printf("%c",*z++);
```

move `z` so that it points to the end of the string at the end of the loop. You need to reset it to point to the start of the string.

**Problem 4**

And then, you have

```
  if(*z=='a')
  {
     printf("present");
     *z++;
  }
```

That is a problem. `z` does not move unless `*z` is `'a'`.

Fixed up `verify`:

```
// You don't need the input to be of type char**
void verify(char* em)
{
   char *z = em;
   while(*z)
      printf("%c",*z++);

   // Reset where z points
   z = em;

   while(*z!='\n')
   {
      if(*z=='a')
      {
         printf("present");
      }
      else printf("not present");

      // Move z regardless of the value of *z
      ++z;
   }
}
```

Fixed up `main`:

```
int main()
{
    int count=0;
    char *email=malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    printf("enter the email id\n");
    scanf("%100s",email);

    char* it = email;
    while(*it)
        printf("%c",*it++);

    // Just use email, not &email
    verify(email);

    // Deallocate memory
    free(email);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can u explain why you used this// Reset where z points
   z = em;

Comment: Before the `while` loop, `z` points to the first character of the string. After the loop is exited, `z` points to the last character of the string. By using `z = em;`, we make `z` point to the first character of the string again.

Answer (score 0):

don't use *?++ there. you cant never be sure if it is like *?, ?++ or * ?, (*?)++.

```
 void verify(char* em){
 char *z = em;
 while(*z)
 printf("%c",*(z++));//do you realy need to print the email more than once?
 //in the verify() and the main()
// Reset where z points
z = em;

   while(*z!='\n'&&*z!='\0')
   {
  if(*z=='a')
  {
     printf("present");
  }
  else printf("not present");

  // Move z regardless of the value of *z
  ++z;
   }
  }


int main()
{
int count=0;
char *email=malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
printf("enter the email id\n");
scanf("%100s",email);

char* it = email;
while(*it)
    printf("%c",*(it++));

// Just use email, not &email
verify(email);

// Deallocate memory
free(email);

return 0;
}
```